# Regexp to match exactly one word in the beginning of the String in Java

Tags: java, regex

stuck with the way regexp works in java...
Why in Java regexp pattern

```
(\\w+)(\\s{1})is not (\\w+)
```

matches both:

`mary is not tall`
`mary ann is not tall`

How do I change the patter to restrict the name to appear just once, e.g. what i want is:

```
name+ " "+"is"+" "+"not"+" "+"tall"
```

Answer (score 5):

You are just missing an [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) at the start.

```
^(\\w+)\\sis not (\\w+)
```

See it [here at Regexr](http://regexr.com?3590k).

`^` is anchoring the regex to the start of the string. If you don't do this it will match on the string "mary ann is not tall", but from "ann" on "mary **ann is not tall**"